# Is there a survey that describes the most effective approaches for an answer retrieval problem?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, question-answering, information-retrieval

I have a dataset that contains pairs of a question and an answer. My problem is to train a model that can search for the right answer from the pool of my answers given the newly input question, so this is a kind of answer retrieval problem.

Can anyone provide me a survey and effective approaches for this problem?

Comment: What research have you done already?

Comment: As suggested in the previous comment, before asking a question, you should do a little bit of research and tell us what you have or not found. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more details of how to ask a good question.